# dynamic cast smart pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, casting

class TcpTahoe is a subclass of class socket.
Look http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_tcp_tahoe.html 
(I want to simulate a small network.)

Code:

```
Ptr<Socket> ns3TcpSocket;
...
Ptr<TcpTahoe> ptr = dynamic_cast< Ptr<TcpTahoe> >(ns3TcpSocket);
uint32_t ssthresh = ptr->GetSSThresh2();
cout << ssthresh;
```

So i now during runtime, ns3TcpSocket will be a TcpTahoeSocket.
But i am getting an compilation error.

Regards

Comment: As a regular user of StackOverflow, you probably already know that SO is a question-and-answer site. You may not realize that your post has no question in it. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Sorry i thought my question is obvious. My quistion is, why do i get the compilation error? Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect your question, and please include the *exact* text of the error message. (I get lots of errors when I compile that code, but I bet you have a specific error message in mind.)

Comment: ... where the first few lines of error are a good default option for *the error message in mind*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` can be used to convert into either a pointer or a reference. In your case, `Ptr<TcpTahoe>` is neither. You should use the raw pointer here. I don't know the `Ptr` class, but something along these lines should work:

```
Ptr<TcpTahoe> ptr = dynamic_cast<TcpTahoe*>(ns3TcpSocket->GetRawPtr());
```

(`GetRawPtr()` is made up, of course. Most chances `Ptr`'s `operator&` will do the trick, if exists).

Oh, and bear in mind the `dynamic_cast` might return `NULL` if the cast can't be done. Make sure you treat that case.

Comment: Ahh ok, and i found such a function, but it doesnt work either. Could you please a look at http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_ptr.html#details this is the Ptr class. I tried dynamic_cast< Ptr<TcpTahoe> >(PeekPointer(ns3TcpSocket));

Comment: Try `Ptr<TcpTahoe> ptr(dynamic_cast<TcpTahoe*>(ns3TcpSocket->PeekPointer())`. Do consider reference count issues when using `PeekPointer`, the hour's too late for me...

Comment: sorry forgot my last comment, it works, i made a copy paste mistake. But i dont understand this  dynamic_cast<TcpTahoe*>, i expect this  dynamic_cast< Ptr<TcpTahoe> >

Comment: `dynamic_cast< Ptr<TcpTahoe> >` doesn't work because `Ptr<TcpTahoe>` is neither a reference (`&`) nor a pointer (`*`). Although it wraps a pointer, from the language point of view it's just yet another class.